# Close Modal Box after 10 seconds

Tags: jquery

How can i close the jquery modal box after 10 seconds ???

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

```
//make sure you have lower case "o"
setTimeout(function(){
    $(dialog).close();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Actually this was the code used before, $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
  //Cancel the link behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#mask').hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });

Comment: this close the modal on close button but i want to close it after particular time ...

Comment: The correct command to close a jQuery UI dialog is `$('#elementId').dialog('close');`.

Answer (score 5):

```
setTimeout(function()
{

   // code to close the modal

}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks but i had to choose one as answer so i selected according to time. Sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery UI modal dialog will automatically open on page load if you declare no other parameters in its initialisation call:

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

To have the dialog close after a delay you should be able to include a call further down your DOM ready event:

```
setTimeout($('#dialog').dialog('close'), 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setTimeout` function to delay an action by a number of milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#dialogModal').modal('hide')
}, 10000);
```

where `dialogModal` is the dialog's id attribute, and `10000` is a ten second delay in milliseconds.

You can execute any code in the function block.

Answer (score 1):

Showing #ads modals on page load then close after 10 seconds :

```
    <script>
    $(window).load(function()
    {
    $('#ads').modal('show');});

    $(window).load(function()
    {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ads').modal('hide')
    }, 10000);});
    </script>
```

This code working for me after trying all the other way closing modals :)