# Autoclose Modal Window? How to make modal window automatically close after a while?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

How to make modal window automatically close after a while?

For example: http://ruseller.com/lessons/les2000/demo/index.html. The window popped up, and now I want after 2 seconds that the window will close.

Code here:

```
<div class="remodal-bg"gt;
...Ваш контент...
</div>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
    <h1>Remodal</h1>
    <p>
      Flat, responsive, lightweight, fast, easy customizable modal window plugin
      with declarative state notation and hash tracking.
    </p>
    <br>
    <a class="remodal-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
    <a class="remodal-confirm" href="#">OK</a>
</div>



<a href="#modal">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>


$(document).on('open', '.remodal', function () {
    // открытие окна
    var modal = $(this);
});

$(document).on('opened', '.remodal', function () {
    // окно открыто
    var modal = $(this);
});

$(document).on('close', '.remodal', function () {
    // закрытие окна
    var modal = $(this);
});

$(document).on('closed', '.remodal', function () {
    // окно закрыто
    var modal = $(this);
});

$(document).on('confirm', '.remodal', function () {
    // нажатие на кнопку подтверждения
    var modal = $(this);
});

$(document).on('cancel', '.remodal', function () {
    // нажатие на кнопку отмены
    var modal = $(this);
});


<script>
    var options = {...};
    $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal(options).open();
</script>


var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')];

// открыть модальное окно
inst.open();

// закрыть модальное окно
inst.close();
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your question instead of linking to it. We don't want to have to download your code in order to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close Modal Box after 10 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180276/close-modal-box-after-10-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment is found in the soure of the page where you link to:

```
// You can open or close it like this:
// var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')];
// inst.open();
// inst.close();
```

So you could just wrap the close in a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(inst.close, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to the `open` event and then add a `timeout` of `2000` milliseconds to close it after that time.

```
$(document).on('open', '.remodal', function () {
    console.log('open');
    setTimeout(function(){$(this).remodal('close');},
    2000);
});
```

Comment: Ir sys: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined jquery.js:5986
dt jquery.js:5986
x.extend.buildFragment jquery.js:6543
x.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:6237
x.fn.extend.append jquery.js:6047
Remodal.buildDOM jquery.remodal.js:117
Remodal jquery.remodal.js:98
(anonymous function) jquery.remodal.js:238
x.extend.each jquery.js:657
x.fn.x.each jquery.js:266
$.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.remodal.js:235
(anonymous function)"