# How to set a timeout for a popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a popup that appears when I click a button, but to make it disappear I have to click again. 
Is there a way to set a timer and make it disappear?

This is the code:

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}
.popuptext.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close Modal Box after 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180276/close-modal-box-after-10-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to read into the function `setTimeout()` [on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or [mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which are both two great sites for programming beginners.

Your problem could be solved like shown in the following snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");

  if(popup.classList.contains("show")) // Check if the popup is shown
     setTimeout(() => popup.classList.remove("show"), 10000) // If yes hide it after 10000 milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use setTimeout:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.remove("show");
  }, 10000)
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show div below</button>
<br/>
<div id="myPopup">No longer hidden</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  
  //Try this, setTimeout takes a callback function to be executed after an amount of time, in this case 3000 milliseconds is 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
  },3000)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display= "block"

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display= "none"
   }, 3000);
}
```